# R: DoubleClick Campaign Manager Reporting API data download

Tags: r, api, double-click

We try to download data from DoubleClick Campaign Manager Reporting API
The only script I found is https://github.com/WillemPaling/RDoubleClick

```
#Install using:
library(devtools)
install_github("WillemPaling/RDoubleClick")

#Basic commands to get started:
##Authorise with the API
client.id <- "yourclientid.apps.googleusercontent.com"
client.secret <- "yourclientsecret"

DCAuth(client.id,client.secret)
```

So far everything works fine and authentification is no problem
BUT: when running

```
##Get available profiles (to find your profile ID)
profiles <- userprofiles.list()
```

or

```
 profiles <- userprofiles.list(client.id,client.secret)
```

R produces an error

```
Error in fromJSON(api.request(req.url)) :
could not find function "api.request"
Called from: fromJSON(api.request(req.url))
Browse[1]>
```

[image: R Error message]

Did anyone else encounter these problems? Any known solutions, that I missed? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Seems like something you should submit as an issue to the package on github instead of here.

Comment: I did this already: Issue 2 Error in userprofiles.list(client.id,client.secret). But there was no reply whatsoever. This a second try to find an answer - if there is one.